# Cannot access temporary tables from within a function

Tags: sql-server-2008, function

I would like to get count of specific records. So my query will look like the following...

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    NAME,
    (SELECT...) AS UserCount // Stmt1
FROM MyTable
```

The issue is that, 'Stmt1' is a complex statement and it cannot be written as innerquery. 
Well, I can use functions, but the statement includes 'CREATE TABLE' so I get the following error message

**`Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.`**

What is the best way to accomplish the task ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use user defined table type to solve your problem.

You just create a table variable like

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[yourTypeName] AS TABLE(
    [columeName1] [int] NULL,
    [columeName2] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [columeName3] [varchar](1000) NULL
)
GO
```

and you can declare this table variable in your function like

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[yourFunctionName] 
( 
    @fnVariable1 INT ,
    @yourTypeNameVariable yourTypeName READONLY
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
AS 
BEGIN 

    SELECT .................
        FROM @yourTypeNameVariable 
        WHERE ........
    RETURN @r 
END
```

On your procedure you can declare your table type like

```
DECLARE @yourTypeNamevaribale AS yourTypeName
```

And you can insert values to this table like

```
insert into @yourTypeNamevaribale (col,col,..)values(val,val,..)
```

pass this to your function like

```
dbo.yourFunctionName(fnVariable1 ,@yourTypeNamevaribale )
```

please go for this method, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can not use #temp table.

As you are using SQL Server 2008, why don't you use table variable instead of #temp tables?
Give it a try.

Comment: Agreed use the Declare @TempTable as TABLE
    (
  elementid  int ,
  element  VARCHAR(8000)
    )
instead of #table

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post as I started using table variables and switched to temporary tables for performance reasons only to find temporary tables couldn't be used in a function.

I would be hesitant about using table variables especially if you are playing with large result sets, as these are held in memory. See this post...

[http://totogamboa.com/2010/12/03/speed-matters-subquery-vs-table-variable-vs-temporary-table/](http://web.archive.org/web/20150826220951/http://totogamboa.com/2010/12/03/speed-matters-subquery-vs-table-variable-vs-temporary-table/)

Other alternatives would be..

1. Extracting the temporary table result into another table function.
2. Converting the code into using sub-queries

Comment: table variables are not stored "only in memory": http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/yet-another-temp-tables-vs-table-variables-article

Answer (score 0):

In 99,99% of cases there is no need for any tricks with temp tables or subqueries, but use aggregation functions like `COUNT`, `SUM` or `AVG` in combination with [`OVER` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)  and (often) `PARTITION BY`.

I am not sure what the OP tried to achieve but I assume that the UserCount is somehow related to the values in `MyTable`. So there must be a way to join `MyTable` to whatever table that produces `UserCount`.

The most simple example is to show all users and the total number of users

```
SELECT id
    , name
    , user_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM MyUsers
```